# Cannot login to svn server

Tags: users, authentication, subversion

I have a SVN server on my Raspberry Pi (Raspbian).

It has a project under the directory `/welcome`, I want to add users to it.

My users would be `admin` with password `admin` and `user2` with password `tempuser2`

This is my `authz` file:

```
### This file is an example authorization file for svnserve.
### Its format is identical to that of mod_authz_svn authorization
### files.
### As shown below each section defines authorizations for the path and
### (optional) repository specified by the section name.
### The authorizations follow. An authorization line can refer to:
###  - a single user,
###  - a group of users defined in a special [groups] section,
###  - an alias defined in a special [aliases] section,
###  - all authenticated users, using the '$authenticated' token,
###  - only anonymous users, using the '$anonymous' token,
###  - anyone, using the '*' wildcard.
###
### A match can be inverted by prefixing the rule with '~'. Rules can
### grant read ('r') access, read-write ('rw') access, or no access
### ('').

[aliases]
# joe = /C=XZ/ST=Dessert/L=Snake City/O=Snake Oil, Ltd./OU=Research Institute/C$

[groups]
# harry_and_sally = harry,sally
# harry_sally_and_joe = harry,sally,&joe

# [/foo/bar]
# harry = rw
# &joe = r
# * =

[/welcome]
admin = rw
user2 = rw
```

This is my `passwd` file:

```
### This file is an example password file for svnserve.
### Its format is similar to that of svnserve.conf. As shown in the
### example below it contains one section labelled [users].
### The name and password for each user follow, one account per line.

[users]
# harry = harryssecret
# sally = sallyssecret

admin = admin
user2 = tempuser2
```

The `svnserve.conf`:

```
### This file controls the configuration of the svnserve daemon, if you
### use it to allow access to this repository.  (If you only allow
### access through http: and/or file: URLs, then this file is
### irrelevant.)

### Visit http://subversion.apache.org/ for more information.

[general]

password-db = passwd
auth-access=write

realm = repository-rpi
authz-db=authz
```

I can't commit to that server, it always says "Unauthorized".

What am I missing? (passwd and authz are both in the same directory as svnserve.conf)